# Can we generate simulated data using result of Logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, simulation

I have an outcome y (binary) and two variables x1 and x2 (continuous and independent). I have fitted logistic regression y~x1 and y~x2 in two different datasets, but I don't have a dataset that records both x1, x2 and y. I wish to generate a simulated dataset that follows the two fitted logistic regression (i.e. when I fit y~x1 and y~x2 separately in the simulated dataset, the coefficients should be close to the coefficients I obtained in the two real datasets). I have no clue how to achieve this using R and I wish to learn from you. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) with a single predictor $x$ models the *probability* for $y$ to be TRUE (or 1) as

$$ P(y=1) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta_0+\beta_1x)}. $$

We can now approach your question in two ways. Either you have your estimated coefficients $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$. Or you have a fitted model object from a previous call to `glm()`. Let's do both ways, by first doing the first, then fitting a model to this first simulation, finally simulating from this fitted model.

```
n_sim <- 100           # for the initial dataset
set.seed(2)            # for replicability
xx <- runif(n_sim)     # predictor values
coefficients <- c(1,1) # my assumption
prob <- 1/(1+exp(-(coefficients[1]+coefficients[2]*xx)))
```

This last line corresponds to the formula for $P(y=1)$ above. We now draw $y$ according to these probabilities:

```
yy <- runif(n_sim)<prob
```

This is the core of the simulation.

We can now fit a model to these data:

```
model <- glm(yy~xx,family="binomial")
summary(model)
```

This gives (output truncated):

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.9410     0.4706   2.000   0.0455 *
xx            1.2604     0.9246   1.363   0.1728
```

This is pretty close to the `(1,1)` coefficients we specified above. If we re-run this multiple times with different seeds, we find that the fitted coefficients vary quite wildly.

Finally, we can simulate according to the `model` object that contains the fitted model. This is just a question of calling `predict.glm()` to obtain the new `predicted_probabilities` and then simulating, as above:

```
n_sim_new <- 1000
xx_new <- runif(n_sim_new)
predicted_probabilities <- predict.glm(model,newdata=data.frame(xx=xx_new),type="response")
sim <- runif(n_sim_new)<predicted_probabilities

summary(glm(sim~xx_new,family="binomial"))
```

The result is quite close to the coefficients we found above and used for the simulation:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.7383     0.1458   5.064 4.11e-07 ***
xx_new        1.5356     0.2850   5.387 7.17e-08 ***
```